# Question about Pine Script function overload

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i have an error i dont understand how to fix : The f_top_fractal function has overloads using the same number of parameters without them having distinct types. Function overloads with the same number of parameters must have explicit parameter types that are unique among overloads.
any idea ? thanks

the code line in this error is the following :

```
f_top_fractal(src) =>
    src[4] < src[2] and src[3] < src[2] and src[2] > src[1] and src[2] > src[0]
f_bot_fractal(src) =>
    src[4] > src[2] and src[3] > src[2] and src[2] < src[1] and src[2] < src[0]
f_fractalize(src) =>
    f_top_fractal(src) ? 1 : f_bot_fractal(src) ? -1 : 0
```

Running on V5 pine script , as an indicator its all good , when brought into the strategy i get this. trying to trouble shoot it .

Comment: You'll have to provide more code that reproduces the error. But if I had to guess, you might already have a function or a duplicate with the same declaration.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.